# Rails strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I want to register this params to permit params in rails 4.
I have params like this.

```
"items"=>{"roles"=>{"1"=>{"menus"=>{"1"=>["true"]}}, "2"=>{"menus"=>{"1"=>["true"]}}}}
```

How should I change into permit params.

Thanks all.

Comment: Try this `params.require(:items).permit(roles: [:id, menus: [:id, :your_boolean]])`

Answer (score 0):

Add a function so-called `items_params`

You may well add a `params.require(:items).permit(:roles)`

Or nested permit like `permitted = params.permit("items" => {"roles" => "1"})`

The result will be like

```
permitted["items"]["roles"]["1"]            # => { "menus" => { "1" => ["true"] }

permitted["items"]["roles"]["2"]            # => nil
```